# Dockerize vue js front end and spring boot backend and deploy on kubernetes cluster

Tags: spring-boot, docker, vue.js, npm, kubernetes

I have developed spring boot backend and `vue` `js` front end I could successfully deploy the spring boot app and create cluster `ip` service for spring boot app but I have never work with NPM project on docker and `kubernetes`. I also have problem in `Axios` when I locally testing backend and frontend I give `(localhost:backendport/endpoint)` for `axios` and how can I adapt it to `kubernetes`. should I give cluster `ip` service name instead of `localhost:port/endpoint -> clusteripservice/endpoint` if so how can I externalize the configurations and how can I deploy both app.

here is `Axios` call

```
import axios from 'axios'


const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8084'
//const API_URL = '/'


class UserDataService {


    retrieveAllUsers() {

        return axios.get(`${API_URL}/user/getall`);
    }


}

export default new UserDataService()
```

Answer (score 2):

Idea is to use nginx as your app container and proxy pass to proxy to back-end. So you need to define location for your api, i.e. /api and proxy that.

Then if you are using axios, you would call all back-end endpoints on relative path, i.e.

```
axios.get('/api/v1/myApiPath')
```

So you do not need to worry about hostname in calls to back-end.

Also, for development you similarly use vue.js development settings to also proxy back-end via npm.

See my toy project here for details how it's done:
Deployment piece - https://github.com/taleodor/mafia-deployment
UI piece - https://github.com/taleodor/mafia-vue

Specifically nginx settings with proxy configuration - https://github.com/taleodor/mafia-vue/blob/master/nginx/default.conf (note that it's using websockets which you may remove if you're not using them). Specifically vue development server configuration - https://github.com/taleodor/mafia-vue/blob/master/vue.config.js.

Write up on CI / CD workings (unrelated to your question but maybe useful) - https://itnext.io/building-kubernetes-cicd-pipeline-with-github-actions-argocd-and-reliza-hub-e7120b9be870

Comment: Appreciate your answer and do you have an idea if I use axios then how can I call to backend. in your project I didnt see axios call.

Comment: Updated my answer with a sample axios call - basically you always use relative paths, i.e. axios.get('/api/v1/myApiPath').

Comment: I have another question, I'm working on microservices project and there are few backend spring boot microservices needed to be communicated with vue js front end. what is the best way as you think to connect those to front end ? directly connect to front end or create one backend and connect all other microservices to that backend then main backend connected to frontend but if I go with that approach I've to do repetitive task since I have to code same controller on main backend like other microservices. I need to know best practice and devops approach.