# Relative link not working with nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, devops, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am reverse proxying a NextJs app's base path onto different domains, per country:

```
events {}
http {
    upstream nextjs_upstream {
        server localhost:3000;
    }

    server {
        listen 8080 default_server;

        server_name _;

        server_tokens off;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://nextjs_upstream/us/;
        }
        location /_next/static {
            proxy_pass http://nextjs_upstream/_next/static;
        }
    }
}
```

This is working fine, and I can go to `http://localhost:8080` and see the content I am expecting to see – the page from `http://localhost:3000/us/`.

Moreover, if I add something like this:

```
<Link href='/about-us'>
  <a>NextJs Link</a>
</Link>
```

And click on it, I correctly get sent to `http://localhost:8080/about-us`, which displays content from `http://localhost:3000/us/about-us`.

This is all working as expected, and perfectly.

However, I also have some hardcoded `<a>` tags on the page:

```
<a href="/about-us">
  Normal link
</a>
```

You can see this is a typical relative URL link. However, when I click on it, the browser navigates me to `http://localhost:8080/us/about-us/`, which of course 404s as it is proxied to `http://localhost:3000/us/us/about-us/`, which doesn't exist.

This behaviour also occurs if I do `window.location = '/about-us'` in the browser console, however, the output of `window.location.href` is `"http://localhost:8080/"`.

It looks like the req to `http://localhost:8080/about-us` ends up getting a 308 to `http://localhost:8080/about-us`, but I am not sure why. Even more confusingly, it seems like the behaviour differs based on what browser I use.

What have I done wrong here? Do I need to rewrite the req path, or something?

Comment: To avoid rewrites (which is highly recommended), you shouldn't use path prefixes in proxy pass. See this question and my answer here on general principle on building architecture for this - hope it helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63716880/dockerize-vue-js-front-end-and-spring-boot-backend-and-deploy-on-kubernetes-clus/63779157

Comment: See if these help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60452054/nextjs-deploy-to-a-specific-url-path, https://levelup.gitconnected.com/deploy-your-nextjs-application-on-a-different-base-path-i-e-not-root-1c4d210cce8a

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thanks, but I don't think this is related to NextJs at all. The same URL problems occur if I expose a simple Python server at the origin.

Comment: @j_d, yes that is true with any rendered html. The idea is that generated html should the base url also in its links so that you can build the html with baseurl being provided via a build

Answer (score 3):

Imaging like that:

1/ If my link is: `http://localhost:8080/us/about-us`

2/ It's going to your proxy and meet first condition:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://nextjs_upstream/us/;
}
```

3/ After that, your server will add `us` path to your link and that the reason why it lead to: `http://localhost:3000/us/us/about-us/`

My suggestion is add `if clause` for remove `/us` in your reverse proxy config file:

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^(.*)/us/) {
    rewrite (.*)/us/(.*)$ $1/$2;
}
```

Your config file look like this:

```
events {}
http {
    upstream nextjs_upstream {
        server localhost:3000;
    }

    server {
        listen 8080 default_server;

        server_name _;

        server_tokens off;
        
        if ($request_uri ~ ^(.*)/us/){
            rewrite (.*)/us/(.*)$ $1/$2;
        }
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://nextjs_upstream/us/;
        }
        location /_next/static {
            proxy_pass http://nextjs_upstream/_next/static;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't the `rewrite` condition cause a 302?

Comment: I edited at rewrite in my answer, try it and let me know the result.